# R: t tests on rows of 2 dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, t-test

I have two dataframes and I would like to do independent 2-group t-tests on the rows (i.e. `t.test(y1, y2)` where `y1` is a row in dataframe1 and `y2` is matching row in dataframe2)

whats best way of accomplishing this?

EDIT:
I just found the format: dataframe1[i,] dataframe2[i,]. This will work in a loop. Is that the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach you outlined is reasonable, just make sure to preallocate your storage vector. I'd double check that you really want to compare the rows instead of the columns. Most datasets I work with have each row as a unit of observation and the columns represent separate responses/columns of interest Regardless, it's your data - so if that's what you need to do, here's an approach:

```
#Fake data
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100),10))
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100),10))


#Preallocate results
testresults <- vector("list", nrow(df1))
#For loop
for (j in seq(nrow(df1))){
  testresults[[j]] <- t.test(df1[j,], df2[j,])
}
```

You now have a list that is as long as you have rows in `df1`. I would then recommend using `lapply` and `sapply` to easily extract things out of the list object.

Comment: Thank you for the words of wisdom. I indeed do have to do ttests across the rows, perhaps poor file design on my part. I'll keep it in mind for next time!

Comment: @Chase I wonder whether you can do a paired t-test using 'paired = T' with your solution. At the moment it gives me an error...

Answer (score 3):

It would make more sense to have your  data stored as columns.

You can transpose a data.frame by

```
df1_t <- as.data.frame(t(df1))
df2_t <- as.data.frame(t(df2))
```

Then you can use `mapply` to cycle through the two `data.frames` a column at a time

```
t.test_results <- mapply(t.test, x= df1_t, y = df2_t, SIMPLIFY = F)
```

Or you could use `Map` which is a simple wrapper for `mapply` with  `SIMPLIFY = F` (Thus saving key strokes!)

```
t.test_results <- Map(t.test, x = df1_t, y = df2_t)
```

Comment: am I missing something about why `as.data.frame(t(df1))` wouldn't work?

Comment: @mnel - hah, sounds good. I was second guessing myself there for a minute!